# MYSQL do not show duplicate ID in INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to hide the duplicate `u.u_id` in my database table. I tried using the `SELECT DISTINCT` statement but it is not hiding. Can someone help me? Thank you!

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.u_id, l.l_id, u.fname, u.mname, u.lname, u.dept, u.user_type, u.u_grdsec, e.e_name, l.date_added, DATE(l.date_added)
FROM logs l
INNER JOIN users u ON l.u_id = u.u_id
INNER JOIN establishment e ON l.e_id = e.e_id
WHERE DATE(l.date_added) = CURDATE()
ORDER BY l.date_added DESC;
```

Here is my LOGS table

[image]

Here's the result of the statement above

[image]

Expected result for the `u_id` is something like this

```
+------+
| u_id |
+------+
|  48  |
|  47  |
|  57  |
|  60  | <-- hide the other 60 row
|  71  |
|  66  | <-- hide the other 66 row
|  83  |
|  58  |
|  56  |
|  61  |
|  59  |
|  90  |
|  91  |
|  68  |
+------+
```

SOLUTION:

```
SELECT l.l_id, u.fname, u.mname, u.lname, u.dept, u.user_type, u.u_grdsec, e.e_name, l.date_added, DATE(l.date_added), date_format(l.date_added, '%H:%i') as 'time'
FROM logs l INNER JOIN users u ON l.u_id = u.u_id
INNER JOIN establishment e ON l.e_id = e.e_id
WHERE DATE(l.date_added) = CURDATE()
GROUP BY 
    date_format(l.date_added, '%H:%i'), l.u_id
ORDER BY l.date_added DESC
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih hi! I provided the sample image of my logs table. `u_id` is the one that I'm using to get the information in the `users` table.

Comment: there are two `u_id = 6` rows,  one is `i_id =75` another is `i_id =76` which one did you want to get?

Comment: BTW could you provide yours expect result? and provide **Text** sample data , expect result instead of Image

Comment: @D-Shih I just want to show one `u_id`. For example, there is two `u_id = 6`, I just need to show one `u_id = 6` in the result. I just want to hide the duplicate `u_id`.

Comment: there are two u_id = 6 rows, one is l_id =75 another is l_id =76 which one did you want to get from your sample data.

Comment: @D-Shih I need to get all the data but without the duplicates.

Comment: That makes no sense, you want to remove duplicate data but want to get all data, We would want to help you but could you provide expect result from your sample data?

Comment: @D-Shih I already edited the question with an expected result for the `u_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do groub by i.u_id or apply left join

Comment: `SELECT l.l_id, u.u_id, u.fname, u.mname, u.lname, u.dept, u.user_type, u.u_grdsec, e.e_name, l.date_added, DATE(l.date_added) FROM logs l LEFT JOIN users u ON l.u_id = u.u_id LEFT JOIN establishment e ON l.e_id = e.e_id WHERE DATE(l.date_added) = '$rep_date' GROUP BY u.u_id ORDER BY l.date_added DESC;`. Is this correct?

Comment: It doesn't show any result. I also tried removing the `GROUP BY u.u_id` but it doesn't show any result either.

Comment: Hey. I tried exploring the `GROUP BY` and it works now. It seems like I used the wrong column that's why it didn't show any result. Thank you!